# Bodyguard vs Hunter

Tags: one-night-werewolf

Two questions. The first is the simpler of the two to establish a baseline.

In One Night Ultimate Werewolf with the Daybreak expansion, if the Hunter is killed, and the Hunter and Bodyguard are both pointing at the same player, what happens?

1. Does the Hunter successfully kill the player, or
2. Does the Bodyguard protect the player and thus the player with the third most votes dies (if that player has at least 2 votes)?

I assume it's option 2, the Bodyguard prevails.

Now, to the real question, the scenario that happened today:

- Player 1 gets the most votes
- But the Bodyguard is pointing to Player 1
- The Hunter has the second most votes
- But the Hunter is also pointing at Player 1

The Bodyguard has already protected Player 1 once. Does he protect Player 1 a second time?

Comment: What is the Bodyguard from? It's not from regular One Night Werewolf.

Comment: Correct. It's from the Daybreak expansion. I'll edit the question to make that clearer. The Bodyguard has no night role, but whoever he points at is not killed even if that player has the most votes, instead the player with the second most votes dies. (http://onenightultimate.com/?p=77)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The player that that the hunter pointed to would die because the bodyguards ability only protects from death from votes.

[Rules](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/rules2/OneNightUltimateWerewolfDaybreak-rules.pdf)

> When everyone votes, the player that the bodyguard points to cannot be killed. If that player received the most votes, the player with the next most votes )at least two) is killed.

What would happen is.

- Player 1 gets the most votes
- Bodyguard protects player 1 causing play 2 to get selected instead
- Player 2 turns out to be the hunter and was pointed at player 1
- Player 1 is killed since the bodyguard only protects from votes and not from other abilities
- End result is player 1 and player 2 are killed